# Semper Veritas, Semper Veritatem, or something else?

Tags: idiom, translation-check, tattoo

I'm considering getting a tattoo with the phrase "Always Truth" or "Always the Truth" in Latin, but I'm not 100% how to translate it, because I don't really understand Latin noun declension. My first guess was *Semper Veritas*, and based on *Semper Fidus* and *Semper Fidelis*, I'm guessing that's correct, though *Fidus* and *Fidelis* are adjectives and *Veritas* is a noun, so I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

Further, Google Translate indicates the correct translation is *Semper Veritatem*, though I know better than to assume that Google Translate always knows best, particularly as I suppose this is grammatically more of a sentence fragment than a proper sentence.

Comment: Welcome to the website! You are most completely correct in not trusting Google Translate. Frankly, they are awful at translating Latin. Sometimes, in my free time, I go on Google Translate Community and do some translating and quality control for them. :) It's quite entertaining sometimes...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want something along the lines of *semper fidelis*, I'd suggest a simple *semper verus* "always true", which has the benefit of meaning more than just the literal truth (i.e. loyal, genuine, etc). If you want something a bit fancier, you could go with *semper honestus*. Not only would *honestus* indicate "truthfulness", but in fact mostly "uprightness." It says more about your character.

If you mean it in the sense of "I always want/am looking for the truth," i.e. what's real instead of what's fake, then yes, *semper veritas* is perfectly fine and good.

Comment: "Veritas" alone, btw, is the motto of Harvard. Doesn't seem a stretch to put "semper" next to it.